# When send a meeting invite to a specific user, you get a undeliverable response back from another user

Tags: outlook-2007

We have a user, where it doesn't matter who sends it, but if you send her a meeting invite through outlook (exchange 2007), you get a non-deliverable message back from another user.  Same one all the time though.

I checked her shared calendar properties and removed the user from the list.

I checked and made sure she wasn't using cache mode.

I checked the manage full permissions and send permissions within exchange and the user is not listed.

What am I missing?

Notes:  Using Outlook 2007 with Exchange 2007 on a XP box and Server 2008.

Comment: Just to be clear...

User A sends User B a meeting invite, and User A gets a message that the invite was undeliverable to user C?

Is User B having their email read or mailbox redirected/mirrored to user C?

Comment: That is correct, and No, they are not redirected or forwarding mail either.  I checked that as well.

Comment: Any server-side rules on User B's mailbox?

Comment: No already checked that, but you made me think more about user C.  I checked and there are no server side settings on her account either, but you make me think, I wonder if I check her local computer?  Nahhhh, her shared calendar settings would only be for her..... hummmm

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, remove the delegate permissions: 
1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. Click the Delegates tab.
3. Click the entry for the user who is no longer in the global address list, and then click Remove.
4. Click OK.